# Can this be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does it make sense to reduce this expression: $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$

I know that this does not equal square root of a squared minus square root of b squared. I also know that a has to be bigger than b. Is there anything left to reduce or am I done?

Comment: As it is, this expression cannot be reduced.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It's as reduced as far as it will go.  If we are to assume these are real numbers we can conclude $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2} \le \max(|a|, |b|)$ but that's an inequality and not an expression of its value.

Comment: It doesn't have to be bigger than b.  If b> |a| > 0 then it is smaller than b.  if |a| > |b| nothing about its size compared to b can be concluded.

Comment: I immediately thought pythagoras with the triangle drawn in the complex plane when I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

If $a^2-b^2$ is factored, the factorization results in $(a-b)(a+b)$. Since $a^2-b^2$ is not a square, $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ is as reduced as it can be.